# Penalized least squares in R

Tags: r, regression

*Disclaimer*: It might be a purely R question, but i thought i'd post it here giving the goal.
Using a smaller subset of [movielens](http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/) data , i'm trying to penalize sparsely rated movies by `lambdas` and barely rating users by `zetas` separately:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dslabs)
data("movielens")

RMSE_adj <- function(l, z){
  dat <- movielens  #data set
  mu <- mean(dat$rating) #mean

  b_i <- dat %>% 
    group_by(movieId) %>%
    summarize(b_i = sum(rating - mu)/(n()+l))

  b_u <- dat %>% 
    left_join(b_i, by="movieId") %>%
    group_by(userId) %>%
    summarize(b_u = sum(rating - b_i - mu)/(n()+z))

  predicted_ratings <- 
    dat %>% 
    left_join(b_i, by = "movieId") %>%
    left_join(b_u, by = "userId") %>%
    mutate(pred = mu + b_i + b_u) %>%
    pull(pred)

  return(sqrt(mean((dat$rating - predicted_ratings)^2)))

} 

lambdas <- seq(0, 10, 0.25)
zetas <- seq(0,10, 0.25)

rmses1 <- mapply(RMSE_adj, lambdas, zetas)
```

However, there is no improvement in MSE compared to using lambdas only evidenced by:

```
lambdas[which.min(rmses1)]
[1] 0.25
zetas[which.min(rmses1)]
[1] 0.25
```

I suspect the issue is in `mapply` function which is used pairwise , i.e., for each `l=0.5`, it would pull a `z` such as `z=0.5` when lists are equal. Do I need to use some nested `apply` function to work around?

Comment: Do you need `out <- crossing(lambdas, zetas) %>% mutate(rmses1 = map2(lambdas, zetas, RMSE_adj))`

Comment: the output format looks good, but it produces the min RMSE for lambda = zeta = 0 , meaning no penalty, which i don't think is right